# Capturar separadamente las secciones que tengan un nombre, pero que no coincida con la siguiente sección

Tags: php, regex

**Texto:** Tengo el siguiente texto (en donde se hará los match's):

```
Header 1
Codigo : c001
Nombre : Juan
Total  : 45,78



Header 1
c001
Nombre : Juan
Cantidad : 23
Subtotal : 45.89

Total     : 3410.67

Header 1
Codigo : c002
Nombre : Ana
Total  : 45.89    
Header 1
c001
Nombre : Juan
Cantidad:4
```

**Objetivo:** Como se observa, `Juan` tiene 3 secciones (las 2 primeras y la última). Intento obtener separadamente las secciones de `Juan` (usando su código: `c001` -en algunas secciones pueda que no haya la palabra `Codigo`).

**Código:** Esto es lo que intenté

```
/(Header1.*?c001.*?)Header1/ism
```

Inicia con la palabra `Header 1` y, como no hay ningún texto que delimite la sección, entonces uso el siguiente `Header 1`.

**Problema:** no coincide con todas las secciones, y en algunas coincidencias toma más de una sección.

**Preguntas:**

1. ¿Cuál es la mejor expresión regular que me ayude a capturar cada sección de `Juan`, asumiendo que cada sección es variable, donde los encabezados `Header 1` marcan el inicio y el fin de la sección?
2. ¿Y si quiero identificarlas solamente por su código `c001`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿Cuál seria la expresión regular que me ayude a capturar cada sección de "Juan", asumiendo que cada sección es variable y lo unico que se tiene para identificarlas es su código, ademas de los encabezados `"Header 1"`

Para que coincida con las líneas entre el `Header` y el nombre, tiene que consumir todas las líneas que le siguen, siempre y cuando el inicio de esta línea no esté seguida por un `Header`:

```
^Header 1(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*?
```

[image: estados de debugex.com]

Y luego del nombre, que coincida con lo mismo, todas las líneas que pueda que estén dentro de la misma sección:     <sub>[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Jfk6jJ/1/)</sub>

```
/^Header 1$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*?\RNombre : Juan$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*/mi
```

**Lógica**

**`Subpatrón`            	`Descripción`**                                             
`^Header 1$`           	`Línea completa que coincide con "Header 1"`              
                     	`(modificador /m para que ^ y $ sean inicio/fin de línea)`
`(?:   )*?`            	`Es un grupo que repite el subpatrón cero o más veces:`   
`\R(?!Header ).*+`     	  `Un salto de línea, que no esté seguido por "Header ",` 
                     	    `y coincide con toda la línea`                        
`\RNombre : Juan$`     	`Una línea completa que coincide con el nombre buscado`   
`(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*`	`Más líneas que no empiezan con "Header "`

Lo importante acá es que por cada salto de línea `\R`, estamos usando una inspección negativa ([*negative lookahead*](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) para garantizarnos que no está seguido por una nueva sección:
`\R(?!Header )`.

Esta estructura sirve para buscar una coincidencia, pero devuelve verdadero o falso, sin avanzar el puntero de la posición actual. Una inspección negativa `(?!`…`)` coincide sólo cuando la posición actual **no** está seguida por el patrón dentro de la inspección. PHP lo llama -¡mal!- [declaraciones](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

**Buscar por "código" en vez de nombre**

Si en vez de por nombre, buscamos por código, sólo hay que reemplazar `\RNombre : Juan$` por el patrón que te interese. Por ejemplo,

- si buscamos que el código esté como `Codigo : xxxx` o `xxxx` *exclusivamente*:

  ```
  \R(?:Codigo : )?c001$
  ```
- o que aparezca en cualquier línea al final, usamos `\b` para garantizarnos que sea una palabra completa:

  ```
  \R.*\bc001$
  ```
- o en cualquier parte de la línea, sin importar si es parte de otro código como `abc00123`:

  ```
  \R.*c001.*+
  ```

Ejemplo:

```
/^Header 1$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*?\R(?:Codigo : )?c001$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*/mi
```

**Código:**

Para buscar todas las coincidencias usamos [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$regex = '/^Header 1$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*?\RNombre : Juan$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*/mi';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $texto, $resultado)) {
    //mostrar secciones
    $n = 0;
    foreach ($resultado[0] as &$seccion) {
        echo "\n-----Seccion " . ++$n . "-----\n";
        echo $seccion;
    }
} else {
    echo "No se encontró el nombre";
}
```

Resultado:

```
-----Seccion 1-----
Header 1
Codigo : c001
Nombre : Juan
Total  : 45,78

... etc (las 3 secciones)
```

Demo:

https://ideone.com/Lz1v48

Comment: Las secciones pueden tener mas de 3 lineas.

Comment: @WalterZamalloaPerez Justamente en tu pregunta comentaste que "ocupan cada una 3 líneas" :-/

Comment: Puse 3 lineas por que al formular la pregunta no encontraba el modo de poner 3 o mas lineas diferentes, cuando se publicó note que todo estaba en una linea, luego acepte una edición. Y si, las secciones pueden tener entre 1 y muchas lineas, es mas en algunas secciones pueda que no haya la palabra "Codigo", si quiza me este complicando mucho pero de momento no encuentro la solucion. Sigo investigando, vuestra ayuda me servirá de mucho.

Comment: @Walter para no estar respondiendo y corrigiendo múltiples veces, podrías editar tu pregunta mostrando un ejemplo más significativo?

Comment: Por nombre funciona y como seria por el codigo 'c001', observar que en algunas secciones no aparece la palabra 'codigo'

Comment: La condición es que capture a través del código, en base a lo que me proporcionas, e parece que con esto ya lo logra: Header 1$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*?\R.*c001$(?:\R(?!Header ).*+)*  podrias confirmar?

Comment: @WalterZamalloaPerez claro, siempre y cuando no tengas un código como `aaac001` que quieras evitar

Comment: Perfecto. Felicitaciones Mariano y muy agradecido. Demasiado eficiente stackoverflow.